# Calculate limit of sequence of Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate the limit of: 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2^2}}...\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n^2}})$

Hint: interpret the limit as a sequence of Riemann Sums that converges to a Riemann Integral

I rewrote it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}$ I thought about if I could rewrite it as a Riemann integral but there is no something over n which could define $\delta x$=(b-a)/n. Also, if n tends toward infinity, isn't the sum just 0+0+...+0=0 ? It seems obvious to me that it converges but I don't see how to continue. Thanks for your help !

Comment: well if you need a $1/n$ can factor it out: $1/\sqrt{n^2+i^2}=1/n\cdot 1/\sqrt{1+(i/n)^2}$

Comment: I didn't thought about it ! Thanks for your advice.  Then, dx is  (b-a)/n, so b = a + 1. So i would get the integral of a to a+1 of 1/sqrt(1+i^2) Is that correct ?

Comment: I wrote n^2 instead of 1 sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *but there is no something over n which could define $\delta x$=(b-a)/n.*

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}}}
$$ leading, as $n \to \infty$, to 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$ using a Riemann sum.

Comment: So b would be equal to a+1 and so the integral would be from a to a+1 of 1/sqrt(1+i^2), is that correct ?

Comment: @Poujh here $a=0, \,b=1$

Comment: How do you know that ?

Comment: Is it because when we integrate, we can substitute x with sin(u) using u substitution, and so we get u=arcsin(x) as the antiderivative and so x should be between -1 and 1 ?